# vim: error searching large tags file

Tags: ubuntu, vim

I have a rather large tags file (over 800M) generated from a code tree. When I do ":tj /bla", vim always give me 
    E431: Format error in tag file 
followed by 
    E426: tag not found

If I use the same version of vim with a small tags file (say from a subtree of the same code tree), searching through tags works as expected.

Do vim have problem with large tags file or is this a bug?

The vim version I'm using is 7.3 that come with Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Instead of using an arbitrary tags file you should bisect your 800M tags file progressively and see if the problem persists. I'm not aware of a file size limitation and the error message seems relatively clear (but not precise): if the problem is really a format error, bisection will find it in no time.

Comment: I'm afraid Vim is not the right tool for such use case. The file is way too big.